# Lost Android phone , Google is Forcing to Change Password but how to remote wipe it

Tags: lost-phone

I lost my phone today and I tried to do the remote wipe several times because phone was off and I was impatient.
Now google says there was suspicious activity with my account and I must my password. This is the dilemma for me now.
If I change the password, I may not be able to get the remote wipe but there were 6 notification emails in my mailbox confirm remote wipe has been requested and then google locked me out.
Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: Your phone should be wiped when powered on and connected to Internet. So the command will be executed only if somebody try to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if the thief connected to the **internet**, it would surely work.

Answer (score -1):

You'll need google account which have registered in your lost phone. Search android device manager and follow the instructions.

Answer (score -1):

Until your phone(lost one) is not connected with internet data willn't wipe or factory reset , if anyone found that and used internet on it then its data will certainly  wiped out.